# Como fazer um popup aparecer acima de todos os elementos o filtro de desfoque da página2

Tags: javascript, html, css

Em meu projeto, desejo, ao clicar em um botão, mostrar um Popup na tela, e desfocar o fundo.
O filtro de desfoque e o Popup funcionam conforme eu clico no botão, entretanto, o desfoque fica acima do Popup.

```js
function showEspecs() {
  document.querySelector(".productEspec").style.display = "block";
  document.querySelector(".backdropExample").style.filter = "blur(10px)";
}

function closeEspec() {
  document.querySelector(".productEspec").style.display = "none";
  document.querySelector(".backdropExample").style.filter = "blur(0px)";
}
```

```css
.productEspec {
  width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 40%;
  margin-left: -300px;
  z-index: 9999;
  display: none;
}

.productEspec i {
  font-size: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  color: #3c3c43;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.backdropExample {
  filter: blur(0px);
  transition: 3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="backdropExample">
  <button onclick="showEspecs()" class="btn-infoDestaques zoom-image" type="button"><img style="opacity: 0.3;"
                  src="https://img.icons8.com/sf-ultralight/30/000000/visible.png" /></button>

  <div class="productEspec  w3-animate-zoom">
    <button onclick="closeEspec()" "><i class='bx bx-x-circle'></i></button>
            <h2>Testando PopUp</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi consequatur magnam dolores rem culpa qui,
              ex assumenda tempore doloribus non!</p>
          </div>
</div>
```

Imagem do popup sem o filtro de desfoque
[Imagem do popup sem o filtro de fundo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5lXA.png)

Imagem do que acontece quando eu aplico o desfoque
[Além do filtro desfocar o popup, por algum motivo ele aparece bem mais abaixo do que deveria, sendo que o foi atribuido position:fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXdD1.png)

Não sei se isso tem a ver com pointer-events, z-index, ou algo do tipo. Só queria que o Popup ficasse fixo na tela e acima do desfoque...

Já tentei deixar o botão e o conteúdo do POPUP fora da classe que contém o desfoque. Quando faço isso, o Popup fica fixo na tela, porém o desfoque só começa dele pra baixo e não ao fundo.

Comment: EVITE O USO DE CAPSLOK. VEJA NO [MANUAL DE COMO NÃO FAZER PERGUNTAS](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5505/137387) *NÃO ESCREVA EM CAIXA ALTA TODA A PERGUNTA **E/OU TAMBÉM O TÍTULO**, QUE CONTÉM AS INFORMAÇÕES DO PROBLEMA OU AS DIFICULDADES QUE ESTÁ ENFRENTANDO.*

Answer (score 1):

Então o problema aí é que a div que vc quer mostrar com a aparência "normal" está dentro da div **backdropExample**, ou seja, quando aplica o **`blur`** nela o pop-up também sofre o blur. Pelo código postado na pergunta basta apenas tirar a div com o pop-up para fora do escopo da div mencionada.

> **OBS:** Inseri um texto qualquer na div `backdropExample` só para o exemplo ficar visualmente mais claro

```js
function showEspecs() {
  document.querySelector(".productEspec").style.display = "block";
  document.querySelector(".backdropExample").style.filter = "blur(10px)";
}

function closeEspec() {
  document.querySelector(".productEspec").style.display = "none";
  document.querySelector(".backdropExample").style.filter = "blur(0px)";
}
```

```css
.productEspec {
  width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 40%;
  margin-left: -300px;
  z-index: 9999;
  display: none;
}

.productEspec i {
  font-size: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  color: #3c3c43;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.backdropExample {
  filter: blur(0px);
  transition: 3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="backdropExample">
  <button onclick="showEspecs()" class="btn-infoDestaques zoom-image" type="button">    <img style="opacity: 0.3;" src="https://img.icons8.com/sf-ultralight/30/000000/visible.png" />
  </button>
  <h3>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi consequatur magnam dolores rem culpa qui, ex assumenda tempore doloribus non!</h3>
</div>

<div class="productEspec w3-animate-zoom">
  <button onclick="closeEspec()"><i class="bx bx-x-circle"></i>X</button>
  <h2>Testando PopUp</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi consequatur magnam dolores rem culpa qui, ex assumenda tempore doloribus non!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. O dia inteiro desenvolvendo a página, chega no fim do dia, o cansaço nem me fez pensar em uma coisa tão óbvia. Agora que eu alterei a posição do Popup pra fora da DIV de desfoque, deu certinho. Muito obrigado e muito sucesso para você colega!

Comment: Felipe se a resposta lhe ajudou a sanar sua dúvida, por favor considere aceitá-la como resposta para que sua pergunta fique com o status de respondida.